# Opening emacs from TextMate

Tags: textmate, emacs

I want to launch emacs from TextMate, I tried the method with OTC in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/185141/on-the-command-otc-usage-for-launching-another-app-with-the-file-path-info), but it would be great if I can learn other methods that I can launch emacs from TextMate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a [Bundle](http://manual.macromates.com/en/bundles#bundles) with a [Command](http://manual.macromates.com/en/commands#commands) that launches emacs.

Or

You can install the [GITMate](http://github.com/rsence/projectplus/downloads) plugin, that adds Git badges and an `Open With…` menu in the drawer.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could make a commands to run emacs as follows.

Bundle → Bundle Editor → Edit Commands

[image]

It runs emacs with Command-Control-Option R